# Using auto-layout (or another method) to "scale up" multiple views

Tags: ios, resize, autolayout, scale, viewcontroller

I have a login view controller made in IB sized perfectly for iPhone 5. With the release of iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, I am attempting to use auto layout (or a different method) to basically scale up the controls on the view so that they fill the space and maintain this below appearance. This view is quite complex to auto layout correctly since each view would need to have width/height and spacing in-between adjusted.

I understand this can be done with auto layout by adding a million constraints but I feel there must be a better way to simply "scale up" each view depending on screen size available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard are you using Size Classes. I believe if you do NOT use Size Classes what you have defined in your storyboard will be scaled when presented on the higher screen sizes automagically. You can verify if this is the case with the simulator.

Comment: I am not using size classes. I'll read up and attempt to implement this and return to mark the question later.